# Installing barby barcode generation on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, barcode

After using several non compatible barcode generators gems in rails 3.2, i am trying to use [Barby](https://github.com/toretore/barby). But i have no clue on how to install it. No idea if have to include in gemfile? or install as a plugin?

Readme provides no information about it nor the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: `gem install barby`. This installs the gem, also its useful to install the wrapper [has_barcode](https://github.com/dpickett/has_barcode). I am currently looking how to use this, but went through install process.

Answer (score 4):

Just for anyone still confuse about it, you can put them on `Gemfile` with `gem 'barby'` because the Gem was listed on [Ruby Gems](http://rubygems.org/gems/barby). Just saying.