# how to implement Barcode generator in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to generate barcode using a table id in ruby on rails. I am using Rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.4.3. I have tried it with 'barby' gem but not sure how to mention require 'barby' and other dependencies in rails. When I am trying to enter require method in controller it is showing ' can not load barby' error.

Comment: It is too much to fully describe the answer here.

Comment: Put `gem 'barbie'` in your project `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, then try the example from the README: https://github.com/toretore/barby#example. Does that work? If you still get an error, please show what you've done.

Comment: The `Gemfile` is where all project dependencies are defined (assuming you're using `bundler`, which 99.9% of modern ruby projects do). My above comment about "adding to the `Gemfile`" applies to *any* additional library (gem) you want to use in the project.

Comment: [Installing Barby gem To your rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025827/installing-barby-barcode-generation-on-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails doesn't allow 'require' option in controller so I added all require dependencies in 'application.rb' and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi once you added gem in `Gemfile` and no need to require in controller in Ruby on Rails framework.
Please follow the link below:

[Generation bar-codes using barby](https://makandracards.com/makandra/44918-generating-barcodes-with-the-barby-gem)

Comment: Hi , Not able to add "gem 'barby', require: %w(barby barby/barcode/code_128 barby/outputter/png_outputter)" as it is not allowing to restart server and throwing error.